# Load a .txt file from a location so i can read the content

Tags: python

I am pretty new to programming and I have a task for my university.
I want to ask the user to add a .txt file so i can in some way edit(copy the content) and return it edited. I've already tried some solutions but i am stuck.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

filename = filedialog.askopenfile()
print(filename.name) 
# I have the location of the loaded file C:/Users/...Desktop/text.txt

nameOfFile = os.path.basename(filename.name)
print(nameOfFile) 
# Here i take the text.txt name 

------

here i want the code to load this text.txt 
file knowing its location so i can have acces to it and read it.

-------

fileReadyToRead = open(nameOfFile, 'r')
file_contents = fileReadyToRead.read()
print(file_contents)

fileReadyToRead.close()
```

Conclusion : i want to ask user to add a .txt in program and edit the content.

Comment: Your question seem a little bit unclear for me. You want to load a pre-existed  file or you want to make a new one? you have the directory or do you want to ask the user to give it to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the user to select a `.txt` file and then print its content this works fine :

```
from tkinter import filedialog

filename = filedialog.askopenfile()
fileReadyToRead = open(filename.name, 'r')
file_contents = fileReadyToRead.read()
print(file_contents)
fileReadyToRead.close()
```

If you want to open a TKinter instance that allows the user to open, edit and save a `.txt` file this works :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import codecs


class App():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.root = parent
        self.entry = Text(self.root)
        self.entry.pack() 
        self.button1 = Button(self.root, text='Load', command=self.load_txt)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.button2 = Button(self.root, text='Save', command=self.save_txt)
        self.button2.pack()

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop() 

    def load_txt(self):   
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfile()
        with codecs.open(self.filename.name, 'r') as f:
            file_contents = f.read()
            self.entry.insert(INSERT,file_contents) 

    def save_txt(self):
        text = self.entry.get("1.0",END) 
        with codecs.open(self.filename.name, 'w') as f:
            f.write(text)


app = App(Tk())
app.run()
```